# The way to make YUV Video Player Without Library in C++

Tags: c++, video, image-processing, mfc, video-processing

Hemm... I confuse how to ask this matter in better way... I wish anyone who can understand this.

I'm running to make a video programming in C++. For displaying one frame from .cif format, my program runs well with all the padding and convertion from YUV to bitmap (e.g: for sample video foreman.cif, I can read the first frame of this sequence video). And now, I am facing *maybe* the very basic problem how to read all frames of the .cif file and play them all as a video. I hope there is no suggestion for any library to be used here. Thanks for any suggestion and kindness to answer my question.

Comment: [libSDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) might be relevant...

Comment: Thanks,, I have checked it. but I have to read some information about what libSDL is...